# Playing around with a mutator method

Tags: java, methods, arguments

Hi I have a question on my mind about mutator method. lets say I have a mutator method that stores in 3 variable. However, I would only want to change the value of "int b". "int a" and "int c" stays in their original value, would that be possible?

```
public void setTri(int a, int b, int c)
{
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}

Triangle t = new Triangle(6, 5, 7);
t.setTri(same, 10, same);
```

Comment: What's that you don't understand? If you only want to modify `b`, the mutator should not receive nay other params, so it should be `public void setB(int b) {this.b = b;}`...or am I missing something here?

Comment: You can define a special `int` value that is never really used (maybe `-1`, depending on use case), define it as constant `same` (or better `SAME`) and check for it in `setTri`. If this really makes sense compared to a simple `setB()` method is questionable.

Comment: Yea I thought about creating a stand alone setA, setB, setC, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way.

Comment: Could you define "more efficient" in this case?

Comment: like using the above mutator to directly change 1 value.

Comment: You could do it by having them be objects (e.g. like Integer) and only setting non-null ones. I wouldn't call that more efficient, though. In general having individual setter methods is "cleaner" IMO.